# android - set appropriate database name based on current locale in device

Tags: android, locale

I want to set appropriate database name based on current locale in device. Any advice? Thanks you guys.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private String currentLanguage = "";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    //I want the DATABASE_NAME should depends on current locale in device,
    //if the current language of device is english, DATABASE_NAME = "db_en", 
    //else it is french, DATABASE_NAME = "db_fr"
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your database name in the strings.xml file and localize it. 
More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: but I need to decide the database name before passing to super(). How can I do that?

Comment: Localization takes care of it. 
Let's say your app supports 2 languages, english and spanish.
In `res/values/strings.xml`, you have and entry like `<string name="db_name">db_en</string>`; and 
in `res/values-es/strings.xml`, you have and entry like `<string name="db_name">db_es</string>`
In your code you can use `R.string.db_name` and you will get the db_name that matches your current locale (if exists)